# Multi-checkbox filter with AND relationship results

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using the frameworks below for building out a multi-checkbox filter on my website. This code filters results based on an OR relationship (if has "option1" value OR "option2" value, etc. I want it to function as an AND relationship, so the only results that show would be ones that have values in *all* of the values selected.

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var filterFunc = function() {
  
  var selectedFilters = {};

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
      selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
    }

    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);
  });

  // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
  var $filteredResults = $('.flower');

  // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
  $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

    // filter each .flower element
    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

      var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

      // loop over each category value in the current .flower's data-category
      $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

        // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
        // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
        // set of filters, we only need to match once

        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // if matched is true the current .flower element is returned
      return matched;

    });
  });

  $('.flower').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();
}

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);
```

```css
body {
  font-family:'Arial';
  color:#646464;
}       
.continents-wrap {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  margin:0 5% 0 0;
  padding:0;
}       
.flowers-wrap {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  margin:0 5% 0 0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
}   
.flowers {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
.flowers div {
  float:left;
  width:90%;
  height:68px;
  line-height:68px;
  padding:0 5%;
  background:#eee;
  margin:0 0 1px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flowers-wrap">
  <p><strong>Filter flowers by colour:</strong></p>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="red" id="red" /> Red</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="yellow" id="yellow" /> Yellow</label><br> 
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="pink" id="pink" /> Pink</label><br>                     
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="purple" id="purple" /> Purple</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="green" id="green" /> Green</label><br>  
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="other" id="other" /> Other</label>
  </form>
  <p><strong>Filter flowers by size:</strong></p>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="tiny" id="tiny" /> Tiny</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="small" id="small" /> Small</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="medium" id="medium" /> Medium</label><br> 
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="large" id="large" /> Large</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="giant" id="giant" /> Giant</label>
  </form>  
  <p><strong>Filter flowers by continents:</strong></p>
  <form>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="africa" id="africa" /> Africa </div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="europe" id="europe" />
    Europe</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="asia" id="asia" />
    Asia</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="north-america" id="north-america" />
    North America</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="south-america" id="south-america" />
    South America </div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="antarctica" id="antarctica" />
    Antarctica</label>    
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="australasia" id="australasia" />
    Australasia</div>               
  </form>
</div>

<div class="flowers">
  <div class="flower" data-id="aloe" data-category="green small medium africa">Aloe</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="lavendar" data-category="purple green medium africa europe">Lavender</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="stinging-nettle" data-category="green large africa europe asia">Stinging Nettle</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="gorse" data-category="green yellow large europe">Gorse</div>  
  <div class="flower" data-id="hemp" data-category="green large asia">Hemp</div>  
  <div class="flower" data-id="titan-arum" data-category="purple other giant asia">Titan Arum</div>  
  <div class="flower" data-id="golden-wattle" data-category="green yellow large australasia">Golden Wattle</div>  
  <div class="flower" data-id="purple-prairie-clover" data-category="purple green other medium north-america">Purple Prairie Clover</div> 
  <div class="flower" data-id="camellia" data-category="pink other large north-america">Camellia</div> 
  <div class="flower" data-id="scarlet-carnation" data-category="red medium north-america">Scarlet Carnation</div> 
  <div class="flower" data-id="indian-paintbrush" data-category="red medium north-america">Indian Paintbrush</div>  
  <div class="flower" data-id="moss-verbena" data-category="purple other small south-america">Moss Verbena</div>  
  <div class="flower" data-id="climbing-dayflower" data-category="blue tiny south-america">Climbing Dayflower</div>  
  <div class="flower" data-id="antarctic-pearlwort" data-category="green yellow large antarctica">Antarctic Pearlwort</div>                     
</div>
```

There is this reference in the original notes:

```
        // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
        // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
        // set of filters, we only need to match once

        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
```

Though I don't know how to take this information and change it to AND instead of OR.

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: There is no Codepen link, and there is not enough code here to see what you are doing.  Please include the *minimum* necessary code here, not off-site.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: My apologies @Don'tPanic, I just modified the original post accordingly.